# Sqoop using Java API to import to Hbase tables

Tags: mysql, apache, hadoop, import, sqoop

I have been trying to import data from MySQL Database to Hbase using Sqoop but running into an error through out. Please could you help me on this? (I am using Sqoop 1 )

My Code is as :

```
import com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions.IncrementalMode;
import com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop;


public class SqoopScheduler {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SqoopScheduler.class);

    private static Configuration configuration = null;
    private static SqoopOptions SqoopOptions = new SqoopOptions();
    private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://jira.com:3306/jirarepository";
    private static final String username = "jiraadmin";
    private static final String password = "jiraadmin";
    private static final String splitBy = "issue_id";
    private static final int Counter = 21000;
    private static final String queryString = "select * from issues where issue_id < ";

    private static void setUp() {



        SqoopOptions.setJobName("HBase_SequentialImport");
        SqoopOptions.setMapreduceJobName("HBase_SequentialImport");
        SqoopOptions.setDriverClassName(driver);
        SqoopOptions.setConnectString(connectionString);
        SqoopOptions.setUsername(username);
        SqoopOptions.setPassword(password);
        SqoopOptions.setSplitByCol(splitBy);
        SqoopOptions.setSqlQuery(queryString + Counter + " and $CONDITIONS");
        SqoopOptions.setHBaseBulkLoadEnabled(true);

        SqoopOptions.setHBaseTable("jira_issues");
        SqoopOptions.setHBaseColFamily("issue_detail");
        SqoopOptions.setHBaseRowKeyColumn(splitBy);

    }

    private static int runIt() {
        int res;
        res = new ImportTool().run(SqoopOptions);
        if (res != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Sqoop API Failed - return code : "+ Integer.toString(res));
        }
        return res;
    }




    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        setUp();
        int result = runIt();
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

The error I am running into is as:

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], main() threw exception, java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:60)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:46)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runSubtask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runTask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.access$200(LocalContainerLauncher.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler$1.run(LocalContainerLauncher.java:224)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.fixRelativePart(FileSystem.java:2147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:633)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseBulkImportJob.jobTeardown(HBaseBulkImportJob.java:124)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:282)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importQuery(SqlManager.java:724)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:499)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at SqoopScheduler.runIt(SqoopScheduler.java:61)
    at SqoopScheduler.main(SqoopScheduler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:57)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of attempts found that the error is due to a flaw in the way MySQL map reduce works. It is trying to set the fetch size of the sqoop map reduce job internally where it fails.

Answering this one so that any one else who are stuck with this one can go forward with ease.

All you have to do here is to specify an explicit fetch size in the SqoopOptions like :

```
private static SqoopOptions SqoopOptions = new SqoopOptions();
  SqoopOptions.setFetchSize(2000);
```

And then it should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Change the queryString starting with $CONDITIONS after where clause

```
 private static final String queryString = "select * from issues WHERE \$CONDITIONS AND issue_id < ";



SqoopOptions.setSqlQuery(queryString + Counter);
```

Comment: How would that make a change ? Its a string and wouldn't require escape sequence.